# Сервинг во flask 2

Tags: python, flask

Есть три файла.

Модель ML:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('d:\set.xlsx', header=0)
df_1 = df.drop(['Персона'], axis=1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = df_1
scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(init = "k-means++", n_clusters = 4, n_init=12)
kmeans.fit(X)
labels = kmeans.labels_
df["Маркер"] = labels
    
df_test = [24, 6, 348, 139419]
X_test = pd.DataFrame(df_test)
X_test = X_test.transpose()
scaled_test = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_test)
predicted_label = kmeans.predict(scaled_test)
```

server:

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pickle
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))\
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.labels([[np.array(data)]])
    output = prediction
    return jsonify(output)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

request:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'
r = requests.post(url,json={20, 1, 263, 716693})
print(r.json())
```

Ввод консоли:
python server.py

Ожидание - вывод результата работы модели по набору данных из реквеста.

Результат -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @andreymal установил. Дальше?

Comment: Как-то странно выглядит, что вы в качестве модели сохраняете датафрейм, а не саму модель. Обычно сохраняют ML модель и после загрузки делают `model.predict` на новых данных.

Comment: Нет, если у вас в датафрейме есть все нужные данные для предсказаний, то всё ок. Хотя вот этот код я не понял от слова совсем: `model.labels([[np.array(data)]])` Если `model` - это датафрейм, то что у него за метод `labels`, я о таком вроде не слышал.

Comment: Погодите, для того, чтобы делать сервинг модели у вас должен быть понятный пайплайн - как вы тренируете модель, как она у вас предсказывает что-то по новым данным. С помощью `Flask` вы этот процесс просто делите на этапы и делаете этап предсказания доступным через `Web`. Т.е. вы сначала должны сделать рабочий ML процесс, отладить его, у вас должен быть готовый рабочий код для тренировки модели и предсказаний, а потом уже вы можете пытаться сервить. Вы зря пытаетесь делать сразу и то и другое, так и отлаживаться сложнее и в целом всё менее понятно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128690/discussion-between-crazyelf-and-eugene-venev).